# Are passengers interviewed for Israeli domestic flights in the same way as they are for foreign ones?

Tags: airport-security, israel, domestic-travel

When I fly internationally from Israel, I am routinely given a short interview by security personnel, in which I am asked several questions etc... Because of this, people generally recommend that passengers arrive to the airport 3 hours before their flight departs.

Is this the same for domestic flights from Tel Aviv to Eilat on Israir? Or is this procedure generally only in place for international flights?

Comment: I can't answer the question, but [Israir's advice for domestic flights](http://www.israirairlines.com/?mode=page&page=15470) is: "For flights on jet (ô"à) aircraft passengers should come to the airport an hour and a half before takeoff.
For flights on ATR (ô"à) aircraft passengers should come to the airport an hour before takeoff." They request three hours for international flights.

Comment: @ZachLipton *(ô"à)* - any idea what that means?

Comment: @JanDoggen: It's presumably supposed to read פ"א in Hebrew, but the page specifies the wrong character encoding ([ISO Latin 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) instead of [Windows-1255](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255)), so it turns into [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) instead.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: and what does  פ"א mean in the context of the comment? Google translate tells me that this is "Fa" in English.

Comment: @WoJ: I have no idea, since I don't speak Hebrew.

Comment: @WoJ, it can have several meaning, but none of them is plane/airline/aviation related.

Comment: I can only speak anecdotally (so not an answer), but as an American working in a Muslim country, traveling internally as a tourist in Israel I had no problems, but traveling in/out of Israel was an absolute nightmare with security every single time.  Domestic and International flights I used the same passport for identification.

Comment: פ"א probably means "pnim aretz" (in transliterated Hebrew), which means "within the country" in English, i.e. an internal flight. The original comment has the same misrendered characters for both internal and external flights.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, security interview is done on all domestic Israeli flights as well as all outbound flights and inbound Israeli flights.

To the best of my knowledge, and from my experience there is no difference in the interview and security check between international and domestic flights. With the only difference is that (at least for Israeli citizens) a passport isn't required and other forms of identification can be used, like a driver's licence or an id card.

But, as @Zach Lipton noted in their comment, the entire pre flight process is shorter, so passengers are advised to come only 1-1:30 hours before the flight and not 3 as in International flights:

[Arkia](http://www.arkia.co.il/check-in-c164)(Hebrew site):

> מועדי התייצבות בשדה התעופה לפני מועד הטיסה:
>
> בנתב"ג ובאילת- 1:30 שעות לפני מועד הטיסה.
>
> בשדה דב ובחיפה- 1:15 שעות לפני מועד הטיסה.

My translation:

> Arrival times to the airport before the departure times:
>
> Ben Gution and Eilat - 1:30 hours before departure.
>
> Sde Dov and Haifa - 1:15 hours before departure.

[Israir](http://www.israirairlines.com/?mode=page&page=15470)(English site):

> Domestic flights from Ben Gurion Airport depart from Terminal 1.
>
> For flights on jet (ô"à) aircraft passengers should come to the airport an hour and a half before takeoff.ֿ
>
> For flights on ATR (ô"à) aircraft passengers should come to the airport an hour before takeoff.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, you can get interviewed both for domestic and international trips. Source: it happened to me when I was flying from Eilat to Budapest via Tel Aviv.

But, if you are worried about this because of the time it takes then there's a lot more that happened to me on that day: I was strip searched at the Eilat airport before boarding to Ben Gurion and they repeated the same thing the same darned day at Ben Gurion. I was sitting on a stool in my underwear while they screened my clothing. And they took out and investigated every. single. thing. in my suitcase. This easily takes two-three hours, depending on how much stuff you have.

Next time I took the bus to Eilat :D and took a flight home from Amman, Jordan (although by the time this happened home moved from Budapest to Vancouver, hurray!).

Comment: How long did it take?

Comment: A bit over two hours. The stripping part was not particularly slow but as I said, they opened my suitcase, took out everything piece by piece and investigated each thoroughly. I have very dangerous socks not to mention [teddy bears](http://begemott.deviantart.com/art/sweet-halloween-dreams-42197587).

Comment: As promised... Nice answer.